# Boolean function is always returning false

Tags: java

My program creates a 4x4 grid of JButtons that all have randomised letters as their text values. These JButtons are stored in a 2D array called `diceLayout[][]`. This function is passed a word submitted by the user that is made of said letters.

It needs to check the surrounding letters to see if their letter is equal to the next letter of the word. Should the word be entirely connected, the function will return `true`. If not, the function will return `false`.

However, the function will only return `false` for some reason. I've attached the function below, if you need more of the program let me know. Thanks!

```
private boolean checkWordConnected(String word) {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    String letters[] = word.split("");
    boolean conn = false;
    outerloop: for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (letters[0].equals(diceLayout[i][j].getText().toLowerCase()) 
                    && diceLayout[i][j].getIsClicked()) {
                pos[0] = i;
                pos[1] = j;
                break outerloop;
            } else if (i == 3 && j == 3) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int a = 1; a < letters.length - 1; a++) {
        loop: for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
                int checkPos[] = { pos[0] + i, pos[1] + j };
                if (checkPos[0] < 4 && checkPos[0] > 0 && checkPos[1] > 0 && checkPos[1] < 4) {
                    if (letters[a].equals(diceLayout[checkPos[0]][checkPos[1]].getText().toLowerCase())
                            && diceLayout[checkPos[0]][checkPos[1]].getIsClicked()) {
                        conn = true;
                        System.out.println(conn);
                        pos[0] = checkPos[0];
                        pos[1] = checkPos[1];
                        break loop;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Sample input and output:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3UqP.png)

When the value of this function (with the word passed in) returns, "false" is displayed in the output bar.

The text of the JButtons pressed adds to the String variable createWord, in the submitButton ActionListener, it takes this word and passes it to the function checkValidWord which passes the values again to checkWordConnected and other functions that test the word against criteria

Full code for the Controller class:

```
 /*
  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
  */
  package Controller;

  import Model.Die;
  import Model.Scoreboard;
  import View.GameWindow;
  import View.HelpWindow;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Controller {

private GameWindow view;
private static int pos[] = new int[2];
private Die diceLayout[][];
private String createdWord;

public Controller(){

    view = new GameWindow();
    addHelpListener();
    addSubmitListener();
    diceLayout = view.getDice();
    addDiceListeners();
}

private void submitWord(String word){
    boolean valid = checkValidWord(word);
    System.out.println("Word Validity: " + valid);
    if(valid=true){
        System.out.println("The word ‘"+word+"‘ is valid.");
        setDieClicked(false);
        createdWord="";
    }else{System.out.println("The word ‘"+word+"‘ is not valid.");}
}

private boolean checkValidWord(String word){
    boolean validSpell = validWordDic(word);
    boolean connected = checkWordConnected(word);
    System.out.println("Connected?: "+validSpell);
    if(validSpell&&connected&&word.length()>3){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

private static boolean validWordDic(String word){
    word=word.toLowerCase();
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\sambe\\Desktop\\IPT\\BoggleGame\\res\\dictionary.txt"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (str == word) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}

private boolean checkWordConnected(String word){
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    String letters[] = word.split("");
    boolean conn = false;
    outerloop:
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
            if(letters[0].equals(diceLayout[i][j].getText().toLowerCase())&&diceLayout[i][j].getIsClicked()){
                pos[0]=i;
                pos[1]=j;
                break outerloop;
            }else if(i==3&&j==3){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int a = 1; a<letters.length-1; a++){
        loop:
        for(int i = -1; i < 2; i++){
            for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                int checkPos[] = {pos[0]+i,pos[1]+j};
                if(checkPos[0]<4&&checkPos[0]>0&&checkPos[1]>0&&checkPos[1]<4){
                    if(letters[a].equals(diceLayout[checkPos[0]][checkPos[1]].getText().toLowerCase())&&diceLayout[checkPos[0]][checkPos[1]].getIsClicked()){
                        conn=true;
                        System.out.println(conn);
                        pos[0]=checkPos[0];
                        pos[1]=checkPos[1];
                        break loop;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return conn;
}

private void addHelpListener(){
    view.getHelpButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            HelpWindow helpWin = new HelpWindow();
            System.out.println("done");
        } 
    });
}

private void addSubmitListener(){
    view.getSubmitButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("done");
            if(!"".equals(view.getSubmitField().getText())){
                submitWord(view.getSubmitField().getText());
            }else{
                submitWord(createdWord);
            }
            view.getSubmitField().setText("");
            setDieColourNull();
        } 
    });
}

private void addDiceListeners(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            Die die = diceLayout[i][j];
            die.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    if(!die.getIsClicked()){
                        die.setClicked(true);
                        if(createdWord==null){
                            createdWord=die.getText();
                        }else{
                            createdWord=createdWord+die.getText();
                        }
                        System.out.println(createdWord); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private void setDieColourNull(){
    for(int i =0; i<4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
            diceLayout[i][j].setBackground(new JButton().getBackground());
        }
    }
}

private void setDieClicked(boolean bool){
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            diceLayout[i][j].setClicked(bool);
        }
    }
}

private int scoreWord(String word){
    int score=0;
    if(word.length()==3){
        score=1;
    }else if(word.length()==4){
        score=1;
    }else if(word.length()==5){
        score=2;
    }else if(word.length()==6){
        score=3;
    }else if(word.length()==7){
        score=5;
    }else if(word.length()>=8){
        score=11;
    }
    return score;
}
}
```

Oh and, I know there are many other problems with this program, but this is the one I'm focusing on currently.

Comment: should `loop:` label be one line earlier, before the "a" for loop?

Comment: *It needs to check the surrounding letters to see if their letter is equal to the next letter of the word* Can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: Please provide the sample input and desired output out of it

Comment: It does not work because you have 5 nested statements, making it hard to understand what it does. Try to split the code in several small methods. It will make things easier and help you spot the problem.

Comment: This should be resolved using a debugger.

Comment: I am not sure why you need the `outerloop` since it is only checking the very first letter (it works by the way). It's the other loop that does not work correctly. Maybe you could roll up the problem from the other side and simplify your program. Instead of looping through all buttons, trying to find the correct letter in the word, why not loop over your word's letters and try to find a corresponding button? When you find the index `i,j` of your first letter, you check if the next letter is between `i-1` and `i+1`  and `j-1` and `j+1` (as long as they exist).

Comment: simplifying means: no labels, not more than two cascading loops and avoid breaks - they make your program's flow way too complicated to read, thus too complicated to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you an example on how you could inverse your search by checking if you find the next letter near the current letter. I simplified the surrounding program and just used a static array `diceLayout` instead of buttons. And to show you how the algorithm works I also added some useless `System.out.println`.

```
public class Dices {

    private static String[][] diceLayout = new String[4][4];   // instead of the button array a static String array

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        diceLayout[0] = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
        diceLayout[1] = new String[]{"e", "f", "g", "h"};
        diceLayout[2] = new String[]{"i", "j", "k", "l"};
        diceLayout[3] = new String[]{"m", "n", "o", "p"};

        String word = "bfkl";  // simple test
        System.out.println(checkWordConnected(word));
    }

    private static boolean checkWordConnected(String word) {
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        String[] letters = word.split("");

        int[] nextPosition = getFirstPosition(letters[0]);    // nextPosition will always hold the i and j indices of the letter you are looking for
        if (nextPosition != null) {                           // if it is not null, then the very first letter of the word is in the array
            System.out.println("found " + letters[0]+ " at " + Arrays.toString(nextPosition));
        } else {
            return false;                                     // if it is null, then we don't even have the first letter and the result is false
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {            // now let's check the other letters
            nextPosition = getNextPosition(letters[i], nextPosition[0], nextPosition[1]);
            if (nextPosition != null) {
                System.out.println("found " + letters[i] + " at " + Arrays.toString(nextPosition));                                  // we continue when we found our next position
            } else {
                return false;                                // otherwise the word is not complete
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // this is a helper method to find the first i and j index (the first position)
    // it is only called once and when it finds the indices of the very first letter,
    // it will return these indices as an int array. If the letter is not in the 
    // array, our position is null (the resulting int[] will be null)
    private static int[] getFirstPosition(String letter) {
        for (int i = 0; i < diceLayout.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < diceLayout[i].length; j++) {
                if (diceLayout[i][j].toLowerCase().equals(letter)) {
                    return new int[]{i, j};
                }
            }
        }
        return null;  
    }

    // this will find the index of the next letter, if it is near the current index
    // meaning, for every i we check if the letter is somewhere in between 
    // i-1 and i+1 
    // and for every j we check if the letter is in between j-1 and j+1
    private static int[] getNextPosition(String letter, int i, int j) {
        for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++) {
            for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++) {
                if (check(letter, k, l)) {
                    return new int[]{k, l};
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // thats the actual method where we check if the letter is at the
    // indicated index. But first we have to make sure that the index is valid
    // and does not go out of bounds (not smaller than 0 and not greater than the array's length)
    private static boolean check(String letter, int i, int j) {
        System.out.println("checking " + i + " " + j);
        if (i >= 0 && i < diceLayout.length && j >= 0 && j < diceLayout[i].length) {
            return diceLayout[i][j].equals(letter);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know, this answer cannot be applied directly to your problem - and it is quite long and complicated to understand. But I still hope that it will help you find your own solution. (And this time without labels and too many loops :)